# What waste products do cells secrete in culture, and at what rate?

Tags: cell-biology, metabolism, biophysics

I am designing microfluidic chips for mammalian cell culture. One aspect I am interested in modeling is the rate at which I must renew media to ensure that:

1. Cells receive enough nutrients
2. Cytotoxic waste products are removed before they reach concentrations that would be detrimental to the cells.

Number 1 is fairly easy. Numbers for glucose uptake rate, for example, are available for many cell types. Number 2 is proving more challenging. I cannot find articles that detail secreted metabolites, including their secretion rate and the relationship between their concentration in media and toxic (or other) effects on cells.

Are there any resources out there on quantitative assessment of secreted metabolic waste?